# How to set default value of a template driven form input in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

This is just a basic input element I have in my form which I need to set its default initial value.

```
<input type="number" name="interest_rate" [(ngModel)]="interest_rate">
```

In my code, I added

```
this.form.controls['interest_rate'].patchValue(this.assumptions.interest_rate*100);
```

But I'm getting

```
Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'patchValue' of undefined
```

Answer (score 6):

To set default value, just set `interest_rate` property of a respective component.

```
@Component({
  ...
  template: `<input type="number" name="interest_rate" [(ngModel)]="interest_rate">`
})

class M {
   interest_rate = 3;
}
```